# (Akka-HTTP) How to specify a custom reason?

Tags: akka-http

I am trying to respond with a custom reason code. For example:

```
404 Didn't find it anywhere!
```

or

```
400 Bad Request: missing parameter 'a'
```

How is this done with Akka HTTP?

Comment: I dont think it's possible since Status code is a sealed abstract class: https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/StatusCode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you mean a custom `status code` or a custom `reason`.

To return a 404 status code you can simply return:

```
HttpResponse(404)
```

To return a customized reason you can return:

```
HttpResponse().withStatus(StatusCodes.custom(404, "Didn't find it anywhere!", ""))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was after a custom 'reason'.

Comment: I had to do `HttpResponse(StatusCodes.custom(404, "Didn't find it anywhere!", ""))` to be able to use it in the scala high level api.